# connection timed out after ddwrt install

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I got a new 1043, v1.10, downgraded it to the german firmware. It was working fine. Than I tried to upgrade with factory-to-ddwrt.bin, build 21061.

Now I get an error when I try to reach 192.168.1.1:

> The server at 192.168.1.1 is taking too long to respond.

I have already tried 30/30/30 reset.
What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

After leaving it to rest for a few hours, checking ipconfig on the computer has shown that the IP address of the router is 192.168.11.1.

The ddwrt forum confirmed it is not uncommon with the tp-link wr1043nd.